# React get data from parent component when child click event hit

Tags: react-native, parent-child

I have a reusable child component called "toolbar"
Toolbar has a collection of buttons (new, save, save & close, history, etc)
When these buttons are fired i want to either clear the data from the parent (new) or execute an API call to save the data and so on.

My issue is the parent has a form and React-Tabulator table populated with data(from api call) I need a way to see the child click event on the parent, to get the data from the form and call getData() on the table, then pass those updated values to the child (have no buttons on the parent) for save or to clear the form and remove the table data if new is pressed.
Toolbar

```
class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }
saveTbBtnClick =()=>{
      var uRl = this.props.nav +"Save";
      var data = this.props.dataPassed;

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: uRl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'':JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success == true){
                window.alert("Successfully saved ")
            }
            else{
                alert("Guess what didn't happen with the data")
            }
        },
        error: function(data){alert("Error")}
    });
}
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="Toolbar">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css"></link>
      <div id="tbControls">
         <button id="newTbBtn"  className="fa fa-plus" onClick={this.newTbBtnClick} />
         <button id="saveTbBtn" className="far fa-save" onClick={this.saveTbBtnClick} />
         <button id="saveCloseTbBtn" className="fas fa-save" onClick={this.saveCloseTbBtnClick}/>
         <button id="refreshTbBtn" onClick={this.refreshTbBtnClick} className="fa fa-sync"> </button>
         <button id="copyTbBtn" onClick={this.copyTbBtnClick} className="far fa-copy" > </button>
         <button id="historyTbBtn"> History <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> </button>
         <button id="viewUserTbBtn" onClick={this.viewUserTbBtn} hidden={this.props.VUvisibility}>View Users</button>
         <button id="deleteTbBtn" className="far fa-trash-alt" onClick={this.deleteTbBtnClick}></button>

      </div>



    </div>
  );
}
}
export default Toolbar;
```

Parent Component

```
class Trade extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
this.state={...}

render(){ 
  return (
<div>
       <div id="ToolBarMenu">
        <Toolbar id="TradeToolbar" dataPassed={this.state.data} VUvisibility={true} nav= 
        {this.state.api}></Toolbar>
      </div> 

<div id="TradeInputs">
            <form id="TradeForm">
              <p>
                <label>Name </label>
                <input id="txtbxTradeName"></input>
              </p>
              <br />

                <p>
                  <label id="TradeDescriptionlbl">Description </label>
                  <textarea id="txtbxTradeDescription"></textarea>
                </p>
              <br/>

              <p>
                <label id="TradeTimeCodeslbl">Default Time Codes</label>
                <select id="TradeTimeCodes" name="Time Codes" multiple>
                  <option value="RSS">RSS</option>
                </select>
              </p>

            <br /><br />
            </form>
            <label>Additional Questions</label><br /><br />
            <ReactTabulator id="TradeAdditionalQuestions" data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns} options={this.state.options} ref={ref => (this.ref =ref)}/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi HK-47, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: You are seriously my hero. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have all the function's in parent component only and pass them to child component, and just call the function from child component whenever required.

For example, move `saveTbBtnClick` function to parent component

```
saveTbBtnClick =()=>{
      var uRl = this.state.api +"Save";
      var data = this.state.data;

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: uRl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'':JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success == true){
                window.alert("Successfully saved ")
            }
            else{
                alert("Guess what didn't happen with the data")
            }
        },
        error: function(data){alert("Error")}
    });
}
```

Pass this function to child,

```
<Toolbar 
   id="TradeToolbar" 
   dataPassed={this.state.data} //pass the data only when required in child component
   VUvisibility={true} 
   nav={this.state.api}  //pass the data only when required in child component
   saveTbBtnClick={this.saveTbBtnClick}  //pass the function here
/>
```

And finally you can call that function as,

```
<button id="saveTbBtn" className="far fa-save" onClick={this.props.saveTbBtnClick} />
```

Like this you can have all the functions in parent component only and pass them to child and call appropriately.